# Averaging set of rasters using Raster Calculator of ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, arcgis-9.2

How do I average a set of rasters?

I have remotely sensed chlorophyll a rasters for several days and I need to get an average of the days represented as one raster layer.

I am using ArcMap 9.2.

Answer (score 9):

in ArcMap 9.2 using the Raster calculator (Spatial Analyst).

for five raster files:

```
( [raster1]+[raster2]+[raster3]+[raster4]+[raster5] )/5
```

Comment: The syntax in the raster calculator in QGIS is also pretty much similar.

Comment: Thanks so much, I thought I had tried that but must have been typing something wrong! All sorted now :)

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the Raster Calculator resulted in the solution I was looking for. I've attached an image of the tool for reference. Thank you[image: ![Example of Raster Calculator]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqAmO.jpg)