# Averaging large number of raster layers using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I have a large number of rasters (300+) I would like to average using Raster Calculator as is explained at [Averaging set of rasters using Raster Calculator of ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44793) I know I can manually select each raster by double-clicking, hitting the '+' key, and then dividing by the total number of files.

Is there a less tedious way to get the average raster, without having to double-click and hit "+" hundreds of times? (or typing each raster's filename into the box, or something similarly tedious)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @FelixIP said, use **[Cell Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/cell-statistics.htm)**. You'll need the Spatial Analyst license, however.

[image]

Alternatively, if you don't have access to Spatial Analyst, and you're familiar with python, you could use arcpy.  What I would do is:

1. Loop through each raster and convert them to numpy arrays using [**RasterToNumpyArray**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/rastertonumpyarray-function.htm).
2. As you're looping through the rasters, store each numpy array into another numpy array (an array of arrays).
3. [**Calculate the mean**](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) of that array.
4. Convert that back to a raster using **[NumpyArrayToRaster](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/numpyarraytoraster-function.htm)**.

I haven't tried this, but I'm pretty sure it should work.

Comment: I just reread your question and see you have spatial analyst, which should be obvious.  I'll leave the alternative solution for others who may not have it.

Comment: @PolyGeo something wrong here. What happened to my comments. Why it is not here anymore?